# Recursive query issues using flask sqlalchemy and 2.0 syntax

Tags: sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, data-modeling

I'm working on creating a query that recursively calls on all the parent objects. I have added some raw data on how I'm expecting this to work.

Class:

```
    class Menu(db.Model):
        __talbename__="menu"
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(200), index=False, unique=False, nullable=False)
        parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("menu.id"))

        children = db.relationship("Menu", backref="parent", remote_side=id)
```

route:

```
    cte = db.session.execute(db.select(Menu))
    cte = cte.union_all(
        db.session.query(Menu).filter(Menu.parent_id == cte.c.id)
    )
    result = db.session.execute(db.select(Menu))

    return result
```

Here's some placeholder data
[image: data]

I guess I am not truly understanding what the cte method is doing. Any suggestions?